# How can I clear the cache associated with WinJS.xhr?

Tags: caching, windows-8, visual-studio-2012, xmlhttprequest, winjs

I'm making a foray into app development on Windows 8 using the WinJS library and Visual Studio 2012 (Update 1), and am experiencing difficulties with WinJS.xhr caching responses from an external REST API I'm querying from within my app.

I partly fixed the problem by modifying the server to send responses with the "Expires" header set to value "0".

However, there are still old responses stuck in the cache from before I modified the server's response headers, going back two days now. I can't figure out how to clear the cache associated with WinJS.xhr -- is there a programmatic way to do that? An option/tool buried in Visual Studio?

Answer (score 0):

Send the request with the `If-Modified-Since` header like this:

```
WinJS.xhr({ 
    url: "http://www.microsoft.com",
    headers: {
        "If-Modified-Since": "Mon, 27 Mar 1972 00:00:00 GMT"
    } })
    .done(function complete(result) {
        // Report download.
        xhrDiv.innerText = "Downloaded the page";
        xhrDiv.style.backgroundColor = "#00FF00";
});
```

Linking off of the [`If-Modified-Since`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh868281.aspx) page, additional headers are found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/ms537417.aspx).  The important one is the `CACHE-CONTROL` header. Additional cache directives from [here](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html) include:

```
Cache-Control   = "Cache-Control" ":" 1#cache-directive

cache-directive = cache-request-directive
     | cache-response-directive

cache-request-directive =
       "no-cache"                          ; Section 14.9.1
     | "no-store"                          ; Section 14.9.2
     | "max-age" "=" delta-seconds         ; Section 14.9.3, 14.9.4
     | "max-stale" [ "=" delta-seconds ]   ; Section 14.9.3
     | "min-fresh" "=" delta-seconds       ; Section 14.9.3
     | "no-transform"                      ; Section 14.9.5
     | "only-if-cached"                    ; Section 14.9.4
     | cache-extension                     ; Section 14.9.6

 cache-response-directive =
       "public"                               ; Section 14.9.1
     | "private" [ "=" <"> 1#field-name <"> ] ; Section 14.9.1
     | "no-cache" [ "=" <"> 1#field-name <"> ]; Section 14.9.1
     | "no-store"                             ; Section 14.9.2
     | "no-transform"                         ; Section 14.9.5
     | "must-revalidate"                      ; Section 14.9.4
     | "proxy-revalidate"                     ; Section 14.9.4
     | "max-age" "=" delta-seconds            ; Section 14.9.3
     | "s-maxage" "=" delta-seconds           ; Section 14.9.3
     | cache-extension                        ; Section 14.9.6
```

From [here](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.9.4):

> Sometimes a user agent might want or need to insist that a cache
>   revalidate its cache entry with the origin server (and not just with
>   the next cache along the path to the origin server), or to reload its
>   cache entry from the origin server. End-to-end revalidation might be
>   necessary if either the cache or the origin server has overestimated
>   the expiration time of the cached response. End-to-end reload may be
>   necessary if the cache entry has become corrupted for some reason.

and

> Specific end-to-end revalidation
>
> The request includes a "max-age=0" cache-control directive,
>   which forces each cache along the path to the origin server to revalidate
>   its own entry, if any, with the next cache or server. The initial
>   request includes a cache-validating conditional with the client's
>   current validator.

Comment: Thank you, but that's not what I'm asking, and I have tried what you suggested. The content associated with some URLs is stuck in the cache, and at this point it seems that adding the "If-Modified-Since" header to the WinJS.xhr request has no effect if that resource was requested prior to the time I started setting the "Expires" header in my REST API's responses. I need to forcibly evict entries in the cache used by WinJS.xhr, or to clear its cache entirely. It's possible too that WinJS.xhr is buggy, but I haven't seen any confirmed reports.

Comment: WinJS.xhr is a very thin wrapper around XmlHttpRequest. Use the same techniques you would use there.

Comment: This is not really a question about HTTP request/response headers, though I fully acknowledge those concepts are important and have affected my app's development. I have tried a variety of req/res header combinations in an attempt to *effectively* purge the cache, and the reality is that those settings aren't affecting the already cached resources (i.e. cached before I started setting "Expires"). Now, that may mean WinJS.xhr is buggy (i.e. not respecting the headers). But whether it is or not, I need to *purge* its cache *directly*. And my original question remains -- how can I do that?

Comment: I think the headers are the correct way to clear the caches.  Without knowing which ones you've tried it's hard to figure out why it isn't working.  Have you tried the "max-age=0" directive?